# Child goes crazy (almost possesed) when woken up from a nap in car

Tags: naps

Our 4 and a half year old has done this for the past 6 months. If she falls asleep in the car for an afternoon nap, when she wakes up she goes BERZERK!
She'll start kicking the back of the front seat, tries to kick her brother in the car seat next to her, etc. She's inconsolable.

She basically is screaming that she needs to get out of the car...and sometimes we can't accommodate her.

In general she is a sweet girl. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 3):

It could be a recurring nightmare, especially one that involves being trapped in a car seat or car.  You might consider stopping and hugging her until she calms down, but not getting out of the car, when that's possible.  If both parents are in the car, one could sit next to her so as to reassure her more immediately if she wakes up from a nap.